# What does this C syntax do: iVar = (*DAT)(param_2,PTR_s);

Tags: c, decompiling, ghidra

i am quite new to reverse engineering and using Ghidra. Recently i have decompiled some arduino code. When i was looking at the decompiled code i noticed the following line.

```
iVar = (*DAT)(param_2,PTR_s);
```

I have cut of some parts of the variables. But i really wonder what this piece of code is doing. It is supposed to be decompiled c code. I have worked a bit with C, 2 years ago, but i cannot figure out what is happening here. PTR_s is supposed to be a pointer to a string and param_2 is a byte*. Havent figured out what *DAT exactly is.

Comment: `DAT` is probably a pointer to a function which is being called here.

Comment: It is a reference to several functions, which made it weird for me to understand

Comment: Well, we don't see the definition. You do.

Comment: Some reading on [C function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Ah thanks i understand the syntax now. *DAT is a function pointer and the two values in the second parentheses are the parameters for the function.

Answer (score 2):

`DAT` is a pointer to a function, which is being (needlessly) deferenced, then called with the two arguments `param_2` and `PTR_s`. The return value is then stored in the variable `iVar`.

Here is a very short and rather silly sample program in which the above statement appears:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*DAT)(int, int) = add;
    const int param_2 = 17;
    const int PTR_s = 25;
    const int iVar = (*DAT)(param_2, PTR_s);
    printf("I got %d\n", iVar);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the sum of 17 and 25, i.e. the output is:

```
I got 42
```

Comment: `DAT` could be a pointer to a pointer to a function, in that case the dereferencing is justified?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure, that 's true. Good point, I guess, and impossible to tell without further context.